# UpdatePanel not being selected properly on mouse over of child control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following snippet of code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelFred">
      <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="divMandatory" style="cursor: pointer; vertical-align: bottom; color:     #dc143c; font-size: 16px;"
                runat="server" onmouseover="jQuery('#MandatoryModalPopup').show();" onmousedown="jQuery('#MandatoryModalPopup').hide();">
                    <span id="starspan"  style="cursor: pointer; vertical-align: bottom; horiz-align: center;  color: #dc143c; font-size: 16px;" runat="server" onmouseover="$('#UpdatePanelFred').Update();">*</span>
            </div>
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

when I mouse over the span, i get this error

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'Update'**

From what I understand, this means I am not selecting the UpdatePanelFred UpdatePanel.

My knowledge of jQuery is very limited and I am sure I am missing something super basic.

Fridays.....

Comment: Are you actually trying to cause a partial postback (update the UpdatePanel) on span mouseover?

Comment: Actually what I am trying to do is that on the mouseover and i have popup gridview.  I want to gridview to refresh before popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to refresh your update panel from client-side code, try changing your span mouseover to:

```
onmouseover="__doPostBack('UpdatePanelFred', '');"
```

But perhaps you should reconsider your approach. Imagine user constantly waving mouse over it - that will cause multiple postbacks.

Comment: I guess i could put a boolean at beginning of callback to make sure the basket is dirty (which is what would require a rebind of the grid)

Comment: If this is on client side then yes, just don't do a "__doPostBack" if not nessesery

Comment: your postback works, but i do believe my approach is not good at all.  I will likely delete this question after our convo is finished.  I guess i am a little out of my comfort zone here.  but what i have is this. I popup a gridview when mouse goes over an asterisk to show some data.  When a user adds an item to the basket, i must refresh the grid to reflect the added items.  if i click on any navigation it update the panels and everything is fine.  However, when I had something to basket, there is not updates to div outside the caller`s div, so i need a way to manually update the updatepanel

Comment: Why don't you update the grid *at the time* when user adds item to basket? UpdatePanel can have external triggers so it can be updated for example on button click that adds item to basket

Comment: I have been trying to do that.. but since the button and updatepanel are in different divs, I am having a hard time selecting the UpdatePanel from the buttonClicked Event.

Comment: No problem, my pleasure. Btw, you don't have to do it in buttonClicked event, in fact you don't have to do it in code at all. Just declare that button as one of `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ` triggers for UpdatePanel - and the update panel will refresh automatically whenever that button is clicked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39504/discussion-between-serenitynow-and-yuriy-galanter)